# Rails 3 jquery date picker date not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I submit my form I can see the date being sent to in the post.  However, It doesn't save the date.  If I do a date check it says it is not in the proper format.  Here is my date picker function, it displays fine:

```
    $j(function(){
    $j("#mile_date").datepicker();
});
```

the $j is because I am using prototype as well so all jquery calls are using the the noconflict variable.

Here is the post:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"Fj4HW/B4EOan/vcPZLJ75TvWkRH4ZKSFsPLlQLSD0cI=", "mile"=>{"odometer"=>"", "trip"=>"428.2
", "gallons"=>"24.959", "note"=>"", "temperature"=>"", "date"=>"06/22/2011"}, "commit"=>"Create Mile"}
```

So it sends the date fine but rails doesn't seem to like the format.  It inserts a null value into the database.  If I submit it with the default datefield with the drop downs it sends this and saves fine:

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"Fj4HW/B4EOan/vcPZLJ75TvWkRH4ZKSFsPLlQLSD0cI=", "mile"=>{"odometer"=>"", "trip"=>"428.2
", "gallons"=>"24.959", "mpg"=>"17.156136063144", "note"=>"", "temperature"=>"", "date(1i)"=>"2011", "date(2i)"=>"6", "date(3i)"=>"22"}, "c
ommit"=>"Create Mile"}
```

In the insert statement it inserts the date as:`'2011-06-22'`

Does Rails expect the date in 3 variables to construct the date format correctly?  How can I get the datepicker to send the correct date format?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  One solution is to simply change the format that the datepicker uses:

```
// in your javascript...
$j(function(){
  $j("#mile_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Rails seems to be able to handle the yy-mm-dd format - I'm using that and am having no issues saving the date to the database.  The only issue here is that some might find the yy-mm-dd format a little less good looking than mm/dd/yyyy...

Comment: Posted a solution where user sees one way and you submit proper format with hidden_field.  Again thanks for pointing to original problem since I saw elsewhere that rails would convert the date.

Comment: just for people running in the same problem, the name of the parameter is `format` and not `dateFormat` anymore

Answer (score 20):

As noted by @BaronVonBraun above rails doesn't seem to handle that format.  Changing it as he suggested worked.  However, for those wanting a different format than yy-mm-dd you can use the following.  The user sees the format you want while rails gets the format it needs.

```
$j(function(){
    $j("#show_date").datepicker({altField: '#mile_date', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

The show_date is the id of the field they see and the mile_date is a hidden field with the date rails needs.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#options).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using the [jquery_datepicker gem](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker) , you'll want to use something similar to the following code in your rails view.

```
<%= form.hidden_field(:ship_date, :id => "ship_date") %>   
<%= datepicker_input(:show_date, item.id, :size => 10, altField: "#ship_date", altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', :value => item.ship_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))%>
```

You can also use `form.datepicker_input` to attach the the date picker directly to the form, but in my use case, I wanted the date picker to reflect the localized date, which Rails would not accept. So I added a hidden form element and set the alternate field to it, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Or try the delocalize gem: https://github.com/clemens/delocalize

Answer (score 0):

```
j('.jquery-calendar').datepicker().each(function(){
  // convert dates from db to US format
  var $input = j(this)
  var found = $input.val().match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/);
  if(found){
    $input.val(found[2]+'/'+found[3]+'/'+found[1]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of hacky but made a helper the set things straight when I know I am giving the server dates in the mm-dd-yy format

```
def convert_to_y_m_d(date)
  new_date = date.split("-")[2] + "-" + date.split("-")[0] + "-" + date.split("-")[1]
  new_date
end
```