# Rails field "can't be blank", even though it's not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm using Rails 3 and failing to submit a form because one of the fields fails to pass `validates_presence_of`. My model is called `dinner`, and the field, which is used in conjunction with a datepicker, is called `date`.

**`views/dinners/new.html.erb:`**

```
<%= f.text_field :date,  id: "datepicker" %>
```

**`models/dinner.rb:`**

```
attr_accessible :date
validates_presence_of :date
```

**`dinners_controller.rb:`**

```
def create
  @dinner = Dinner.new params[:dinner]
  if @dinner.save
    flash[:notice] = "Dinner created successfully."
    redirect_to controller: 'dinners'
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = @dinner.errors.full_messages.join("<br>").html_safe
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

Whenever I fill out all of the fields, including `date`, I get the error "Date can't be blank", even though it is not blank. What's going on here?

Comment: Usually when something like this happens, I find it's a parameter that's not passed the way it should be. Check the server log. Is the :date parameter getting passed at all? If so, is it formatted correctly? Try logging out the `@dinner` object before you try to save it, see if it has a date set.

Comment: Another thing to investigate in cases like this, is how it behaves on the rails console. When you do `d= Dinner.new(:date => "31/12/2012")` does `d.errors` show the same "can't be blank"?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. `@dinner` never has `date` set when I log it out, but trying it over the console works fine.

Comment: Definitely something wrong with the parameter passing, then. Try logging out `params` during the action (or just look at the server log). That should tell you whether the date isn't getting passed at all, or if it's a problem with the format it's sent in.

Comment: Just checked. Strangely, the date _is_ set in the POST request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer.

My `date` column was of type `date`, and before validation Rails ran `.to_date` on it. Unfortunately, the [datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) that I use creates dates in the American `mm/dd/yy` format, which Rails can't handle, so `.to_date` returned nil. That's why the date failed validation: because it really was nil, even though the POST request was fine.

I chose the easy solution and changed the default date of datepicker, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181318/805556).

Note: For my version of datepicker, I had to use `format` instead of `dateFormat`, *and also* had to use `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of `yy-mm-dd` because Rails `String#to_date` thinks that the year "13" is literally '0013' and not '2013'.